# how to rotate element in firefox

Tags: css, 3d, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a div like http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/HKpAX/

Which looks better in chrome than firefox, but why ? Does firefox not support these kinds of rotations or did I miss a css property ?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `px` in `perspective` attribute

```
.container {
    height: 100% ;
    width: 100% ;
    -webkit-perspective: 200px ; 
       -moz-perspective: 200px ; /* 200px instead of 200 */

    margin-left:200px ;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HKpAX/1/)